# Importing data from an excel sheet to a web form

Tags: vba, web, excel-2010

I have an excel template on which I would like to validate data entered by users, and on click of a button on the spreadsheet, I'd like to get the entered information on to a 3rd party web form, which is used to keep track of the user input. 
Is this possible using macros/vba for MS Excel 2010? If yes, I would like some help with the code as well...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of thing is possible.  Before we start giving you code, we will need to see what you have done, know what you are trying to accomplish, and what the errors are.

Because it appears that you are just getting started down the road of IE Automation here are a few websites I used initially to get started.

http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/using-vba-to-automate-internet-explorer-sessions-from-an-excel-spreadsheet/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx

I hope this helps you get started too.